# "CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error" from web server; works normally when browsed from local file system

Tags: html, css, web, iis-6, font-face

I have this embedded font face in the CSS of a web page that I am developing:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('fonts/myfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/myfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/myfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/myfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And further down in the CSS file I use the font:

```
#finder-entry-container h1
    {
        font-family:'myfont', Sans-Serif;
        font-size:28px;
        color:white;
        font-weight:normal
    }
```

When I use this font on a web page, it renders perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, in IE I receive this error:

> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
>   myfont.eot

Even stranger; the page renders just fine when browsed from the local file system (I am using a simple HTML file to troubleshoot this issue.)

Has anyone else had an issue like this? I know the fonts work fine because I can browse them from the local file system, so I don't think it is a file conversion issue. My web server is running IIS 6; I checked the headers for all of the fonts and these are the MIME types that they are returning:

> `myfont.eot` returns `application/octet-stream`
>   `myfont.woff` returns `application/font-woff`
>   `myfont.ttf` returns `application/octet-stream`
>   `myfont.svg` returns `image/svg+xml`

Answer (score 1):

When moving into a directory include the ./ to move into your fonts directory

Try formatting your @font-face declaration like this...

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'myfont';
src: url('./fonts/myfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('./fonts/myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('./fonts/myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('./fonts/myfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('./fonts/myfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: The page renders fine when browsed from the local file system, so pointing to the fonts directory isn't the issue. I tried using this font declaration and it still doesn't work on the server...

Comment: Surprisingly this fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: In my case it's bootstrap's glyphicons and I don't want to modify the bootstrap bower package's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `'?#iefix'` after `.eot`

```
src: url('myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I just found this solution it worked for me so i share it here.Please tell me what exactly would U like to know. And Use this Font converter upload Your TTf here [link](http://transfonter.org/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Github Font Awesome Wiki](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#fonts-not-rendering-properly-running-windows-10)  the solution is to "remove all occurrences of

```
?v=4.x.y
```

from the  @font-face  property in the  font-awesome.css".  Which if you are using LESS, means changing the /less/fa/path.less file.